# transform.LookAt is going off the gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am casting some spell and i am setting it direction by `LookAt`. Problem is that `LookAt` is setting my spell animation off the gameobject. Object from which i am getting position has scale (3, 3, 3), mesh renderer, sphere collider,  and rigidbody. (other colliders are on child objects). Here is the code i am using for casting spell:

```
public void castSpell(GameObject caster, Transform otherTransform, float duration)
{
    if(animationEnabled)
    {
        foreach(var a in animator)
        {
            foreach(var b in a.bools)
            {
                a.animator.SetBool(b.parameterName, b.parameterValue);
            }
            foreach(var i in a.ints)
            {
                a.animator.SetInteger(i.parameterName, i.parameterValue);
            }
            foreach(var f in a.floats)
            {
                a.animator.SetFloat(f.parameterName, f.parameterValue);
            }
        }
    }

    GameObject Temporary_Spell_Handler;
    Temporary_Spell_Handler = Instantiate(_Spell, Spell_Emitter.transform.position, Spell_Emitter.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    ParticleSystemRenderer pr = Temporary_Spell_Handler.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(caster.transform.position, otherTransform.position);

    //Add Spell Script to the casted spell so it handes damage and everything about spells.
    Spell tempSpell = Temporary_Spell_Handler.GetComponent<Spell>();
    tempSpell.caster = caster;

    if(b_lenghtScale)
    {
        pr.lengthScale = -lenghtScale;
    }

    if(lookAtEnemy)
    {
        Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.LookAt(otherTransform);
    }

    Destroy(Temporary_Spell_Handler, duration);
}
```

and here is the image how it looks like:

[image]

I found the problem. My `ball` is scaled to (3, 3, 3), so it went up and pivot of the object stayed down. So how can I overcome this problem?[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Can you add a screenshot of what you *expect* to happen?

Comment: you see that lightning is going to the ground, not to the ball (talking about center of thunder). So i want to change angle somehow.

Comment: That's going to entirely depend on the setup and nature of your objects there. If the graphic of the lightning bolt isn't aligned with the axis of the game object, then the graphic needs to be fixed. If the prefab plane isn't aligned with the axis, then that needs to be fixed. If the prefab axis isn't pointing to where you want it to be pointing, then that's *a different problem entirely.* I can't tell which one it is from the picture you have posted.

Comment: Can you tell me what else should i printscreen for you so i post all images at once

Comment: It's more of a process: pause your scene when the lightning bolt is there and examine the objects to see if the parent (the cloned prefab) is pointing in the right direction. If it's pointing in the right direction, then check each child until you find which one isn't properly oriented.

Comment: @Draco18s i found the problem so i will edit my question and if you know solution please answer.

Comment: Ah. Just to be certain: the ball is a child object of the yellow disk?

Comment: I found solution. I will post the answer

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created empty `gameobject` and make it a parent to my `ball`. Then i set gameobjects position (it is pivot now) to where i wont (around center of ball y=5) and then on the ball i did the opposite (y= -5).

Then to the gameobject i created as pivot i added tag `pivotChange` and then in my `castSpell` script i made this change at `lookAtEnemy` part:

```
    if(lookAtEnemy)
    {
        if(other.transform.parent != null && other.transform.parent.gameObject.tag == "pivotChange")
        {
            Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.LookAt(other.transform.parent.gameObject.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            Temporary_Spell_Handler.transform.LookAt(other.transform);
        }
    }
```

And it is working okay.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. :) Basically what the problem was is that your prefab's pivot location was in one place (on the ground where that yellow disk was) and in order to get it to aim properly you needed to have a child object (or new parent object) that had its pivot in the desired location.  It was my first guess as to the problem, but I had no way to be sure, but I did impart a little knowledge on how to debug it. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot :)